# Flash webservice (remoting) calls in CS5 using Flash 10

Tags: php, flash, web-services, remoting, amfphp

I'm finding little info out there on using Flash and remoting services.  Currently I'm starting out using AMFPHP which works pretty well for sending back simple sets of data but I'd like to send back complex query types which translate to RecordSets.  I have two problems:

1) Is this the way it's currently done?  PHP backend with AMFPHP for webservices so my Flash program can access it?  Or should I be using a different setup?

2) How do I add the mx.remoting services in CS5?  The only docs I find say to add it under Other Panels but I don't have the next area under that in CS5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adobe & Zend Framework are collaborating so I believe that ZF is one of the main current ways.

Have a look at this 
http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/flex_php.html

I know it deals with Flex but it may set you in the right direction. There's quite a few articles & tutorials on the internet dealing with Flash / Zend Framework.

In any case , this is the solution I use myself , although I don't use the Flash IDE , rather FlashBuilder , which I use to develop Actionscript projects.

Hope it helps!

Comment: I accepted this late because it took me a while to get around to figuring out that Flash Builder was the direction I needed to go.  I tried to hold out on Flash CS5, but it just didn't have the programming capabilities I have come to know and love.

Comment: I haven't looked back since I moved to Flex then FlashBuilder with pure Actionscript 3 projects!